Issues connecting Spring Boot application to new ELK server after migration
I had an ELK server that I needed to shut down and replace with a new one. I had a Java Spring Boot project that was connected to the original ELK server. After moving to the new server, all the indices were reset, and I lost all previous data.
Now, I am encountering issues trying to connect my Spring Boot application to the new ELK server. I have verified that the ELK server is running and is accessible. However, when I start my Spring Boot application, I receive the following error:
2024-10-31T00:42:37.816+03:00  WARN 9020 --- [data-leak-service] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Controller' defined in file [Controller.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'Service' defined in file [Service.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'DataRepository' defined in DataRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticSearchConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations' ...

I suspect that this issue may be related to the ELK configuration. Here is my current configuration:
@Configuration 
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${ElasticUrl}")
    private String elkUrl;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
        // Set up credentials provider for basic authentication
        BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
        );

        // Configure RestClient with authentication
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(elkUrl))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder ->
                        httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider))
                .build();

        // Set up transport with Jackson JSON mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // Return the authenticated Elasticsearch client
        return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
}

Additionally, I added the property for automatic index creation in my application.properties:
spring.elasticsearch.index.auto-create=true

I am using the following dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>

I am using the Elasticsearch client version 8.15.1.
Previously, I had a different configuration that worked without authentication:
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
        // Create the low-level client (without authentication)
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create("http://elkip:9200")).build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson JSON mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // Create the Elasticsearch client
        return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
}

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Additionally, what steps do I need to take to enable automatic index creation?

You code seems OK, any more error stack ?

No, I don't take error anymore.

I solve this problem by reading the documentation of Elasticsearch Guide [8.15]. If you have issues with it, you can also follow documentation. I also share my code here:
 @Bean
public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(elkUrl))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                @Override
                public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                    return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                }
            });

    RestClient restClient = builder.build();
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

    return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
}


You don't need any of that code if you just use spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch as a dependency and set up the properties according to the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html#appendix.application-properties.data
Look for the spring.elasticsearch properties. It will greatly simplify your configuration.
Properties you might want to set :

spring.elasticsearch.username

spring.elasticsearch.password

spring.elasticsearch.path-prefix


Prefix added to the path of every request sent to Elasticsearch.

spring.elasticsearch.uris

Comma-separated list of the Elasticsearch instances to use.
